# Should a register page contain every field at once?

Tags: forms, user-behavior

I am redesigning an application, and part of that is making the UX a bit better.
However, the application requires the user to fill in a lot of information.

Would it be better to have them fill out every field (all twelve of them) when registering, of should I let them register and confirm their account, then have them fill in the more specific data on their profile page?
I am leaning towards the second option, telling them that they have to do so in the registering form.

My consideration is that this way, the user doesn't run the risk of losing all their input, including password and email, if something goes wrong after the forms passes client-side validation. It also makes the form a bit easier to fit nicely into a page without having an out-of-place registering form.

Comment: Can the user do anything without this other profile information entered? The registration should have the bare minimum required information. If they can atleast browse the site after registering without profile info then save it for later.

Comment: The user can use the site without extra information, but the purpose of signing up is that they can be found through the search box. Without at least some of the fields filled out, signing up is useless on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a 12 step registration will kill your signup dead

Registration should be limited to as few fields as possible such as user name password.

On first sign in then you can ask for the rest of the profile information and make this optional unless it is explicitly required by the system in which case you clearly state why it is being asked and how it benefits the user

Answer (score 5):

Don't have them fill out all details on the registration page.

It is known in the UX community that the more fields you have when it comes to registering (and checking out for that matter) causes more friction than it should. Only have them fill out the needed information to access their account for later, then have them fill everything else when they gain access to their account (and even then it should be optional).

Comment: pretty much. registration sucks

Comment: Right. Consider that users are in your app to do things and registration (and other form-filling) is an obstacle to those things.